# ASP.NET Friendly url takes time to affect

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, global-asax, friendly-url

I'm using [friendly url](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls/) but when I changed the global.asax file to change the urls it takes 15 to 20 minutes to take effect. 
How can I avoid this delay ?

I used this for my global.asax :

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("root", "", "~/home.aspx");
}}
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: try this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547251/ASP-NetplusWebFormspluscanplusdoplusFriendlyUrlspl